# ICustomFormatter that works with uint.ToString

Tags: c#, iformatprovider, iformattable

Is it possible to create an `ICustomFormatter` that works with a uint with `ToString()`?

I have the following FormatProvider

```
    internal class IPFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {
        public object? GetFormat(Type? formatType)
        {
            if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            {
                return this;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public string Format(string? format, object? arg, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
        {
            if (arg is uint ipAddress)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
                {
                    return ipAddress.ToString(); // Fallback to default ToString()
                }

                switch (format.ToUpperInvariant())
                {
                    case "D":
                        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ipAddress);
                        Array.Reverse(bytes); // Reverse the byte order to handle little-endian systems
                        return string.Join(".", bytes);
                    case "H":
                        return ipAddress.ToString("X8");
                    default:
                        return ipAddress.ToString(format, formatProvider);
                }
            }

            return arg?.ToString(); // Fallback to default ToString()
        }
    }
```

The following:

```
uint ipAddress = 3232235776; // Example IP address value (192.168.1.0 in dot notation)

Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new IPFormatProvider(),"{0:D}",ipAddress)); // Output: 192.168.1.0
Console.WriteLine(ipAddress.ToString("D", new IPFormatProvider()));         // Output: 192.168.1.0
```

Results in:

```
192.168.0.1
3232235776
```

Running it through a debugger the `GetFormat()` is not even called for the `ToString()` variant.

It's like `ToString()` refuses to use the `ICustomFormatter` when the `format=="D"`.

Also when picking another letter, eg `format=="Y"` the `ToString()` variant throws an Exception:

```
System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Format specifier was invalid.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Number.NumberToString(ValueStringBuilder& sb, NumberBuffer& number, Char format, Int32 nMaxDigits, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Number.<FormatUInt32>g__FormatUInt32Slow|42_0(UInt32 value, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.UInt32.ToString(String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in
```

This seems to be because

```
formatType != typeof(ICustomFormatter)
```

instead, looking in the debugger, `formatType` is a  `NumberFormatInfo()`

Is it possible to use to use a `ICustomFormatter` for `UInt32.ToString()`?

Comment: I think it's not possible. See the [documentation's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint32.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-uint32-tostring(system-string-system-iformatprovider)) remarks. `GetFormat` must return a `NumberFormatInfo` object.